# Kusto row_cumsum modifying the Term if Term reaches a point

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, adx

I have a list of Employee names and Salaries in the following order

[image: "Alice", 1, 1000, "Alice", 2, 2000, "Alice", 3, 1400, "Alice", 3, 1400, "Alice", 3, 1400,]

I need to create the output table in the below format. ie, whenever the accumulated salary-total crosses 3000 I have to detect that and mark that row.

[image]

I have tried to do row_cumsum and reset the *Term* once it crossed 3000 but it didn't work for the second iteration.

```
datatable (name:string, month:int, salary:long)
[
    "Alice", 1, 1000,
    "Alice", 2, 2000,
    "Alice", 3, 1400,
    "Alice", 3, 1400,
    "Alice", 3, 1400,
]
| order by name asc, month asc
| extend total=row_cumsum(salary) 
| extend total=iff(total >=3000,total-prev(total),total)
```

Comment: Hi Justin, there's going to be an elegant way to achieve this later this month. We'll post the solution here as soon as it's available.

Comment: Great! Thanks Slavik : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now possible with [scan operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator):

```
datatable (name:string, salary:long)
[
    "Alice", 1000,
    "Alice", 2000,
    "Alice", 1400,
    "Alice", 1400,
    "Alice", 1400,
    "Alice", 1000,
    "Bob", 2400,
    "Bob", 1000,
    "Bob", 1000
]
| sort by name asc
| scan declare (total:long) with 
(
    step s: true => total = iff(isnull(s.total) or name != s.name, salary, iff(s.total < 3000, s.total + salary, salary));
)
| extend boundary_detected = iff(total >= 3000, 1, long(null))
```

| name | salary | total | boundary_detected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 1000 | 1000 |  |
| Alice | 2000 | 3000 | 1 |
| Alice | 1400 | 1400 |  |
| Alice | 1400 | 2800 |  |
| Alice | 1400 | 4200 | 1 |
| Alice | 1000 | 1000 |  |
| Bob | 2400 | 2400 |  |
| Bob | 1000 | 3400 | 1 |
| Bob | 1000 | 1000 |  |

Comment: This feature is available only on EngineV3 clusters as per documentation. Accepting the answer. Thanks