# Kusto memory status for an operation id

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I executed the following control command

```
.set-or-append async XXXX<|fillXXXX()
```

This returned me an operation id

Now I want to check how much CPU/MEMORY usage (Query stats) happened for this operation id.
How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the command, you also get the ClientRequestId, and that's what you should use to get the resources used to run the command, :

```
.show commands
| where StartedOn > ago(1d)
| where ClientActivityId == "KE.RunCommand;9763ec24-910c-4e86-a823-339db440216e"
| where CommandType == "TableSetOrAppend"
| project ResourcesUtilization
```

Comment: When I run .set-or-append async XXXX<|fillXXXX() I only got operation id. But I filtered out using Text using the .show commands to get to the query I ran.

Comment: If you run the command from Kusto Explorer, then you can see the ClientRequestId at the bottom-right corner of the screen (just below the results table).

Comment: Okay i got it. Thank you. @Slavik Would you mind taking a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/65501902/8804776 . Thanks!