# ADX Pagination for query result

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-java-sdk

I have a **function** which returns huge number of rows. I need to paginate this data so that I can efficiently render on the UI. I tried to implement using Stored query results. But unfortunately its in preview mode as per the below link, and shouldn't be used in production.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results#pagination

Based on all these restrictions what is the right way to implement pagination without V3 engine or stored query results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored Query Results is the right path to go.

It's not in Preview anymore, it's a mistake in the documentation, and we'll fix it (you'll see the change within a few days). The feature is GA, and you can definitely use it in Production.

Comment: Great you saved our day. @Slavik can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65501902/kusto-row-cumsum-modifying-the-term-if-term-reaches-a-point

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results still says "Preview"

Comment: Slavik Still in the documentation it is Preview mode, when we contact support team, even they are also saying its preview mode. We are facing a hard time getting approval to build a poc because of this silly documentation issue. :(

Comment: Hi Justin, please check again in a few days ;)

Comment: @JustinMathew stored query results is GA now.